# Rename Setup output with version number

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, setup-project

I have a VS native setup project and want to rename the output MSI file with the current version number as suffix. Currently the output is like "Testapp.msi" and I would prefer "Testapp_2_10_4.msi".

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Couldn't you just try it to find out if it is possible or not? It would be much faster than posting here and waiting for an answer, and you'd have the satisfaction of having figured it out for yourself.

Comment: Unfortunetaly I don't know how to do. I already googled it without any success ;)